# Where chains or similar in Rails to narrow results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

How do you narrow results from a table in Rails?

I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and PostgreSQL and can do

```
users = User.where(:flag1).where(:flag2 => nil)
```

but not

```
users = User.where(:flag1).where(:flag2 => nil).where(:flag3 => nil)
```

to get

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Am I missing something?

I've tried with Squeel, and can similarly do

```
users = User.where{(flag1) & (flag2 == nil)}
```

but not

```
users = User.where{(flag1) & (flag2 == nil) & (flag3 == nil)}
```

which yields

```
!! #<TypeError: Cannot visit Squeel::Nodes::Predicate>
```

Any ideas on how to do this with and/or without Squeel? Thanks!

## UPDATE

The problem for the normal query is caused by the fact that the flag2 and flag3 values can be  either nil or false. I tried to take that into account with Squeel.

I can do

```
User.where{(flag1) & ((flag2.eq nil) | (flag2.eq false))}
```

but not

```
User.where{(flag1) & ((flag2.eq nil) | (flag2.eq false)) & ((flag3.eq nil) | (flag3.eq false))}
```

which returns

```
!! #<TypeError: Cannot visit Squeel::Nodes::Or>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sharing the actual Rails code you've tried? `where` doesn't take a block, yet that's what you're showing (i.e. `where {...}`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about that. Updated the post. Should only be for squeel.

Comment: Could you share what output you're getting for the Rails case that doesn't produce what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now doing

```
User.where{(flag1)}.where{((flag2.eq nil) | (flag2.eq false))}.where{((flag3.eq nil) | (flag3.eq false))}
```

and that seems to work in the Rails console.